# Structuring C++ class hierarchies for maintainability and encapsulation

Tags: c++, data-structures, coding-style, encapsulation

I have some general questions about encapsulation as it relates to maintainability.  Here is an example class that I used to assist in the construction of a parse tree. (I have avoided STL for education's sake.)

The `Node` class describes a node in a tree.  The managing class `ParseTree` (not shown) is responsible for building and maintaining the collection of `Node` objects in a meaningful, tree-like way.

```
// contents of node.h, not including header guard or namespace
class Token;
class Node {
public:
  static const Node* FindParent(const Node* p_root, const Node* p_node);
  static int Height(const Node* p_root);
  static void Print(const Node* p_root);
  Node(const Token * p_tok=0) : p_left_(0), p_right_(0), p_tok_(p_tok) {}
  ~Node() { delete p_left_; delete p_right_; }
  const Node* p_left(void) const { return p_left_; }
  const Node* p_right(void) const { return p_right_; }
  const Token* p_tok(void) const { return p_tok_; }
private:
  friend class ParseTree;
  Node* p_left_;
  Node* p_right_;
  Token* p_tok_;
};
```

The following four topics relate to encapsulation.

1. The static methods in the `Node` class are declared static because they can be phrased without using any private members. I'm wondering if they should live outside `Node` in a common namespace, or maybe as static members within `ParseTree`.  Should my decision be dominated by the fact that `ParseTree` is responsible for trees, and by that logic the functions should live in `ParseTree`?
2. On a related note, the reason the static methods are in `Node` instead of `ParseTree` was because `ParseTree` was filling up with lots of members. I've read that keeping class small and agile is better for maintainability.  Should I be going out of my way to find methods that don't rely on private member access and pull them out of my class definition and put them into functions grouped within the same namespace as the class?
3. I had also read some advice about avoiding mutators on private members since it tends to break encapsulation, so I ended up only having accessors, and let `ParseTree` handle any modifications using its friendship with `Node`.  Is this really better than having mutators and just ending the friendship with `ParseTree`?  If I add mutators, then `Node` can be reused in other contexts without adding another friendship.
4. If I add mutators and remove the static functions from `Node`, I feel like I could just make the data members public and remove all the accessors/mutators/friend declarations.  I have the impression that such an approach would be bad form.  Should I be skeptical of my design if I have accessor/mutator pairs for each private member?
5. If there's anything else obvious and wrong about my approach that I didn't think to ask, I'd appreciate hearing about it.

Comment: Your arguments are going round in circles, which is what happens to me when I think about these kind of issues. I wouldn't worry about it too much, you look like you know what you are doing. But very quickly 1) I don't think they should be in Node. 2) Yes, global functions. 3) I see little advantage in reusing Node, it's not as if there any great worth in it, keep it tied to ParseTree. 4) No, because for something as simple as Node everything public is a possibility.

Comment: 'Mutator', jesus what's wrong with Setters and Getters?

Comment: I spent most of the last several years doing low level work (IC design, hdl's, a spot of embedded C).  A close friend of mine always use to refer to accessors and mutators when he described object oriented design to me, and so that's what I have in my head when I think about public member functions that interact with private members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself, what's a Node? Clearly, it's something that may have a parent, a left child and a right child. It also holds a pointer to some data. Does a node have a height? It depends on the context, is it possible that your nodes may at some point be part of a cycle? A ParseTree has a concept of height, it doesn't seem a node does.

To be honest, I suggest you get your program logic correct first, and then you can worry about the OO bells and whistles.
The questions you're asking will probably answer themselves as you proceed.

Comment: Thanks, the questions you ask lead me down a useful line of thinking.

That said, I finished my program, but I didn't feel like my organization was appropriate.  And I don't yet have a well developed intuition or set of questions I can ask myself for organizing my code.  Additionally, I haven't taken on a large enough problem to see my naive design damage my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think *Node* is a bit too crowded with these accessors, which are apparently just an indirect way of exposing your private members. I think removing these static members to an application namespace would be a bit cleaner. Eg:

```
namespace mycompiler {
    class Node {
        ...
    };

    class ParseTree {
        ...
    };

    const Node* FindParent(...);
    int Height(...);
    void Print(...);
}
```

In that way you could still avoid polluting the global namespace, but at the same time keeping your Node and ParseTree classes smaller. You could also overload some `mycompiler::` functions (e.g. `Print()`) to accept any object from your namespace if you don't want to stick them into your classes. This would make Node and ParseTree more intelligent containers, while some external logic (to the relevant classes) could be isolated in `mycompiler::`.